# VisualSVN: Post-Commit for different projects

Tags: svn, jenkins, tortoisesvn, commit, visualsvn

**my current situation:**

I have a local VisualSVN Server with a repository:

[image]

The whole time I had one project "*Project*", but now I added a second "*Project1*".
I triggered Jenkins with a post-commit:

```
"C:\Users\a.simon\Downloads\curl_7_50_1_openssl_nghttp2_x64\curl" http://localhost:8080/job/CannonAttack-DomMillar/build?token=MyAuth
```

**What I want:**

Now I have this second project and if I change something in the project it has to commit this change. But I have one post-commit. I want that if I commit "*project1*", the post-commit should trigger "*project1*" in Jenkins and if I commit "*project*" it should trigger "*CannonAttack-DomMiller*" in Jenkins.

How can I manage this...? I know that I could just create a second Repository. But is there another way, with two projects in one trunk?